# Derivative of Real parts

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have a term in Equation $Re(X^H ye^{-i\phi})^TB^{\dagger}Re(X^Hye^{-i\phi)}$. I want to take its derivative, I think derivative by parts should be effective but my the answer to this does not match. After setting derivative to zero it should look like this $-2 Im (X^Hye^{-i\phi})^TB^{\dagger}Re(A^Hye^{-i\phi})$.

Thanks a lot for your suggestions
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution above statement should follows as:
 $-Re(X^Hy)^Tcos\phi B^{\dagger} Re(X^Hy)cos\phi$

$$-Re(X^Hy)^T cos^2{\phi}Re(X^Hy)$$

$$-Re(X^Hy)^T2cos\phi sin\phi B^\dagger Re(X^Hy)$$
$$-2Re(X^Hy)^Tcos\phi B^\dagger Re (X^Hy)sin\phi $$
Taking Derivation w.r.t $\phi$
$$-2Re (X^Hy)^T(-sin\phi) B^\dagger Re(X^Hy)cos\phi$$
$$-2Im(X^Hye^{-i\phi})^T B^ {\dagger} Re(X^Hye^{-i\phi})$$

Which is same the answer posted to it.